# Easy Query Builder using Oracle database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, webforms

I have used [Korzh's **EasyQuery.NET builder**](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/).

I need to modify this solution to be connected with an Oracle database, so what are the instructions (code) to build it?

Any help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate about where your stuck, what you have tried, etc.?

Comment: Have you looked [at the company's **documentation** at all?](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what library/components you use to connect Oracle in your application.
Basically you need to use the same format of connection string which is supported in library you are using.
Here you can find the instructions for all main .NET libraries and data providers:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/